# How to show data from database into text in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

i want to show data from database into text box when i press select Button, but i am stuck on it , what i do next , Thanks in Advance

**BootStrapCode**

```
<td><label class="control-label" for="finame" id="myID1" >FIRST NAME</label></td>
<td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase"name="firstname" onkeypress="return allCharacter(event);" ></td>
<td><label  class="control-label" for="mname">MIDDLE NAME</label></td>
<td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="middlename"></td>
<td><label  class="control-label" for="lname" id="myID2">LAST NAME</label></td>
<td><input type="text" class="  form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="lastname" onkeypress="return allCharacter(event);"></td>
```

**php Code**

```
if (isset($_POST['select_button'])) {
  $qrydatabind1 = 'SELECT ecode, first_name, middle_name, last_name, father_name, mother_name,
              number_of_dependents, dob, gender, identification_mark, marital_status, spouse_name, mobile_number,
              email_id, adhar_id, pan_number, passport_number, tin_number, dl_number FROM USER_MASTER';
  $results1 = mysql_query($qrydatabind1) or die(mysql_error());

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results1)) {
    echo '<td><input  type="text" value="{$row["first_name"]}" ></td>';
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working right now? Have you trubbels with your select button, or with displaying the data in the text field?

Comment: What problem you are facing? Question is **UNCLEAR** For Me. And, If You Used More Than 70% of column values in SQL Query, It Would Be Great If You `SELECT *`.

Comment: people asked you what the problem was, you're not responding. There also isn't enough code in this question to support what you're asking, or whatever it is that you're having problems with. Up until then, you may not get the magic answer you're looking for. I for one, have now moved on; good luck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the code. Change the while loop to this one:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results1)) {
    echo '<td><input  type="text" value="' . $row["first_name"] . '" ></td>';
}
```